# How to take log on this expression

Tags: logarithms

I am solving exact differential equation, but I am stuck on the step on how to simplify this term or how to rewrite it.

$e^{-2\ln{\sin{x}}}$

Comment: Is it raised to e??

Comment: yes it is the power of e

Comment: I want to simplify it

Comment: I want to simplify it before differentiating

Comment: Is it this equation?$$e^{-2ln(\sin (x))}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bring the $-2$ inside the logarithm
$$e^{\ln(\sin(x)^{-2})} $$
The logarithm and the exponential function cancel leaving
$$\sin(x)^{-2}$$
Now you can take the derivative using the chain rule:
$$(\sin(x)^{-2})' = -2\sin(x)^{-3} (\sin(x))' = -2\sin(x)^{-3} \cos(x) $$
Which can be rewritten as
$$\dfrac{-2\cos(x)}{\sin(x)^3}$$

Comment: thanks @jens Render Now I think it is the perfect answer.

Answer (score 3):

So $e^{-2ln(sinx)}=(\sin(x))^{-2ln(e)}=\sin^{-2}(x)$ which can be easily differentiated by chain rule . or division rule.

Answer (score 3):

$$e^{-2 \ln (\sin (x))}=(\sin (x))^{-2}=\csc^2(x)$$